# ¿Cómo crear un botón cada 5 segundos con C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buenas a todos y todas.

Estoy aprendiendo Visual C# y estamos haciendo una práctica que consiste en atrapar al botón con el cursor.

Pasados unos puntos de la práctica, tenemos que conseguir mostrar un botón cada 5 segundos.

He estado mirando sobre los Timers pero no se como hacerlo correctamente.

Dejo mi código actual (siento que esté mal):

Clase principal del formulario:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Persona persona;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void btnEscurridizo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Mover botón a una posición determinada.
        //btnEscurridizo.Location = new Point(20, 32);


        //Mover botón a una posición aleatoria.
        //int width;
        //int heigth;
        //width = this.Width - btnEscurridizo.Width-10;
        //heigth = this.Height - btnEscurridizo.Height-50;
        //numero1 = objetoRandom.Next(heigth);
        //numero2 = objetoRandom.Next(width);
        //btnEscurridizo.Location = new Point(numero2,numero1 );

    }



    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //int width;
        //int height;
        //Creamos un objeto de tipo random
        //Random objetoRandom = new Random();
        //Uso del random
        //int locationCursorX = MousePosition.X;
        //int locationCursorY = MousePosition.Y;
        //width = objetoRandom.Next(locationCursorX);
        //height = objetoRandom.Next(locationCursorY);

        //btnEscurridizo.Location = new Point(width, height);
        //boton.location.x(width/2)


    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Creamos un objeto random
        //Random objetoRandom = new Random();
        //int random = objetoRandom.Next(100);
        //Asignar un tamaño automático al cargarse el formulario a btn
        //btnEscurridizo.Size = new Size(random, random);
        //Asignamos un nombre
        //btnEscurridizo.Text = "Persona";

        //Que no salga nombre
        //btnEscurridizo.Text = "";

        //cambiar imagen al cursor
        //this.Cursor = new Cursor(Application.StartupPath + @"\ufo.cur");

        //prueba clase perosona
            Persona persona = new Persona(this.Size);
            //Inyectar botón
            Controls.Add(persona.btnPersona);


        //btnEscurridizo.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;

    }

}
```

Clase de persona:

```
class Persona
{
    //Declaración de variables
    int anchuraPersona;
    int alturaPersona;
    int edad = 0;
    int velocidad = 1;
    public Button btnPersona = new Button();

    public Persona(Size tamañoForm) 
    {
        Random rand = new Random(80);
        //Creamos un random para posicionar el botón y la edad.
        edad = rand.Next();
        //Creamos el objeto timer para inicializar el temporizador
        Timer temporizador = new Timer();
        // Sets the timer interval to 5 seconds.
        temporizador.Interval = 5000;
        temporizador.Start();
        btnPersona.Location = new Point(rand.Next(tamañoForm.Width), rand.Next(tamañoForm.Height));
        btnPersona.BackColor = Color.Red;
        btnPersona.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda. Agradecería encontrar una solución lo más pronto posible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias hacer que la clase sea el boton asi es directo la asignacion de la localizacion

```
public class Persona : Button
{
    //Declaración de variables
    int anchuraPersona;
    int alturaPersona;
    Size dimensionesForm;

    public Persona(Size dimensionesForm) 
    {
        this.dimensionesForm = dimensionesForm

        SetLocation();

        Timer temporizador = new Timer();
        temporizador += timer_Tick(..);

        temporizador.Interval = 5000;
        temporizador.Start();

        this.BackColor = Color.Red;
        this.Visible = true;
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, ..)
    {
        Timer t = (Timer)sender;

        t.Stop();

        SetLocation();

        t.Start();
    }

    private void SetLocation()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        decimal top = rand.Next(0, dimensionesForm.Width);
        decimal left =  rand.Next(0, dimensionesForm.Height);
        this.Location = new Point(top, left);
    }
}
```

como veras el timer interno cambiar el location cuando se cumple el timer

un punto es que el tamaño que asignas serian las dimensiones del form que usarias en el random para limitar los valores que puede seleccionar

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. ¿Habría alguna manera de hacer eso pero sólo en el método persona?

Comment: metodo persona ? por lo que veo en el codigo la persona es una clase no un metodo. Quieres que el timer se declare en el form y no dentro de la clase persona ?

Comment: Te comento. La idea es que el timer se ejecute cada vez que inicias un nuevo objeto persona en el formulario principal, así cuando yo haga new Persona(dimensionesForm), se mostrará un botón y, cada 5 segundos a partir de ese momento, saldrán más botones en el formulario. Por eso pregunto si se puede hacer el timer en el mismo método constructor Persona(dimensionesForm) de persona.